# What's a Logic?

Tags: logic, model-theory, proof-theory

I'm taking a logic course, and so far we've seen

1. Logical Symbols
2. Logical Axioms
3. Rules of Inference
4. Non-Logical Symbols
5. Non-Logical Axioms

Now, I'm confused about definitions.

- Alphabet/Vocabulary = 1+2
- Logic = 1+2+3 ?
- Signature/Language $L$ = 4 OR *Logic (implicitly)*+4 ?
- Theory = 5 OR *Logic (implicitly)*+5 ?
- $L$-Theory = 4 *(implicitly)*+5 OR *Logic (implicitly)*+4 *(implicitly)*+5 ?

Also, I've seen Logic being defined as an ordered pair consisting of a function mapping alphabets to sets of formulae and a so-called satisfaction relation... or by means of institutions in category theory... I'm just confused as to what *a* logic ultimately really *is*, because even the most rigorous logic texts I could find begin their definitions at languages and vocabularies. Or, if not a universal definition, maybe at least what a logic consists of, i.e. foregoing technicalities, what needs to be defined to have a certain logic.

Perhaps the difficulty is that Rules of Inference are more Proof-theoretic and the other stuff more Model-Theoretic, but maybe you can help me anyway, it'd be much appreciatetd.

Comment: I must be conditioned by bad questions, but it took me a while to figure out that "1+2+3", etc. was refering to the numbers in the first list

Comment: Sorry, the only alternative I thought of was $1\cup 2\cup 3$, but I figured that'd be even worse

Answer (score 5):

We start with *Symbols* : either *logical* : $\to, \lnot, \land$ etc. (the *connectives*), the *quantifiers* and *equality* ($=$) and some auxiliary symbols (like parentheses).

In addition we need *propositional variables* : $p_0,p_1,\ldots$ for *propositional logic* as well as predicate symbols : $P,Q,\ldots$ and individual *variables* : $x_0,x_1,\ldots$ for *predicate logic*.

This is enough for the *languages* of "pure" logic : propositional calculus, predicate calculus.

If we want to develop some mathematical theory, we have to enlarge the language of predicate logic with specific mathematical symbols : $\in$ for *set* theory and $0,s(x),+,\times$ for *arithmetical* theory.

Usually, we call the list of the non-logical symbols of a language : [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic)).

Up to now, we have considered only *symbols*, i.e. the alphabet of the language. In order to have a language, we need also *syntax*, i.e. the rules to produce finite strings of symbols that are meaningful : the so-called *well-formed formulas*.

For propositional logic, $(p_0 \to p_1)$ is a wff while $\land p_0$ is not.

For predicate logic, $\forall x (Px \land Qx)$ is an example of wff.

Having defined the syntax of the language, we add the *semantics* to it, based on the concept of [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)).

---

Up to now we have covered the *Language* : your points 1 and 4.

In order to develop a logical *calculus*, we need rules of inference : at least one (usually *Modus Ponens*) but often more than one, as well as some (maybe zero) *logical axioms* : this corresponds to your point 2 and 3.

We may call propositional calculus and predicate calculus with the general term : [Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-algebraic-propositional/#LogiConsRela).

---

Finally, in order to develop a mathematical theory, we have to add to the predicate calculus some specific mathematical axioms, like e.g. [first order version of Peano's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) for *arithemtic* or [Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#Axioms) for *set* theory (and this is point 5).

---

If we denote with $\text L$ a specific language, e.g. the language of predicate calculus with the mathematical symbol $\in$, we can use $\text L$-theory to denote a theory that uses language $\text L$.

---

---

For a more abstract definition, see e.g. Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus et alii [Mathematical logic (Springer, 2nd ed.1994)](https://books.google.it/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA261), **Ch.XIII.1 Logical Systems** :

> In the following definition of a "logical system" we collect several properties
>   which are shared by the logics we have considered so far. As we are mainly interested in semantic aspects, we shall speak of a logical system as soon as we have the following: We are given, for every symbol set $S$, an "abstract" set whose elements play the role of $S$-sentences, and in addition, a relationship between structures and such sentences which corresponds to
>   the satisfaction relation, and determines whether an "abstract" sentence
>   holds in a structure.
>
> **Definition**. A *logical system* $\mathcal L$ consists of a function $L$ and a binary relation $\vDash_{\mathcal L}$. $L$ associates with every symbol set $S$ a set $L(S)$, the set of $S$-*sentences* of $\mathcal L$. The following properties are required: [...]

Comment: When you say "We may call propositional calculus and predicate calculus with the general term : Logic.", do you mean prop. calc. is a logic and pred. calc. is another logic? So logic = logical calculus?

Comment: Also, why limit this conversation to propositional and predicate logic? I mean, doesn't that defeat the point of having a general conversation about all kinds of logics (infinitary, fuzzy, etc.)?

Comment: @BlondCafé - they are the two most common examples of logical calculus. Having agreed on the basic machinery, the extension is straightforward : [Modal Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/) is propositional/predicate calculus with a new logical symbol : $\square$ (necessity) and the relevant logical axioms and rules, and so on.

Comment: Alright, these are pretty clear definitions, which I appreciate a lot, but there's still another aspect to my question: to define a language/theory/$L$-theory, do you need to have already defined a logic (= calculus = logical system (?))? (Just like e.g. to define a $K$-Vector Space you clearly need to have defined a field $K$ beforehand)