# Questions about "What's a Logic?"

Tags: logic, model-theory

Reading https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3376609 I have some questions.

> If we want to develop some mathematical theory, we have to enlarge
> the language of predicate logic with specific mathematical symbols ∈
> for set theory and 0,s(x),+,× for arithmetical theory.

When enlarging the language of predicate logic with let's say arithmetical theory, we should keep P, Q as predicate symbols of the enlarged language? If we dont't keep the symbols, what happens to an expression like $P \land Q \to P$ ? What is the status of an expression like $(0 = s0) \land (s0 = 0) \to (0 = s0)$ in arithmetical theory? Is it true? What is the formal proof in aritmetical theory language?

> In order to develop a logical calculus, we need rules of inference :
> at least one (usually Modus Ponens) but often more than one, as well
> as some (maybe zero) logical axioms : this corresponds to your point 2
> and 3.

The logical axioms (for instance $P \land Q \to P$), in which language are expressed? I see how to write them with predicate symbols like $P, Q$ but not sure at all how can I express them with the enlarged arithmetical theory, especially if we dont't have $P, Q$ symbols available...

> Having defined the syntax of the language, we add the semantics to
> it, based on the concept of interpretation.

If I look at this particular presentation of FOL (https://haslab.github.io/MFES/2122/FOL-handout.pdf) in slide 14 defines what is an interpretation. I guess it is the very same definition that applies in the above sentence, right?

In slide 16 defines the satisfaction relation. Where this satisfaction relation maps with the response we are talking about? It looks like as if the predicate logical axioms were embedded in the definition of satisfaction... Is something like a formal way of saying "classical logic axioms holds"?

EDIT:
A follow-up to make sure I understand the required setup...

For instance when reading the Completeness theorem:
$$\vdash\phi\leftrightarrow\vDash\phi$$

What is the meaning of $\phi$?

What is the meaning of $\vdash$?

What is the meaning of $\vDash$?

$\phi$ is a well formed formula built using a given language $L$.
This particular language must contain enough logical symbols to be able to express enough logical axioms in order to be in classical logic.

$\vdash \phi$ means that there are a proof (a set of formulas built using the language) in which the last one is $\phi$ and that only use logical axioms and rules of inferences.

In particular there are diferents ways,constructions,setups to express classical logic, each one using diferent symbols and diferent logical axioms and rules of inference. As long as you are able to show that they are equivalent no matter which one you choose.

Finally the last one $\vDash \phi$. This one has nothing to do with axioms or deduction rules. It is another way of looking at $\phi$. It means that $\phi$ holds (is true) in the domain of interpretation (the thing we are trying to formalize). $\vDash$ represents the satisfaction relation (Tarsky truth) that any domain must follow.
In particular $\vDash \phi$ means that $\phi$ is true in any of such domains.

So what the theorem says is that anything that can be proved syntactically with only logical axioms, must be true in any world that follows satisfaction and more surprising the other way around, anything that is true in any world that follows satisfaction, can be proved syntactically using only logical axioms.

Anything wrong?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: How it works the chat? Can we ask questions there? Almost all my questions are use and throw...

Comment: You're free to use chat as you please. It's entirely a social thing.

Comment: But keep it PG13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols $P, Q, R$ are not a core part of the language inventory of FOL. You can define a FOL language with $P, Q, R$ as predicate symbols, but you can also have one without them. Often, as in your example, these letters are used not as concrete symbols of an object language, but rather as meta variables, placeholders for arbitrary formulas or predicate symbols when formulating axioms and the like: "Where $P$ and $Q$ are formulas, the pattern $P \land Q \to P$ is true in all interpretations". $P \land Q \to P$ is a formula *scheme* where the letters $P$ and $Q$ are abstractions standing proxy for arbitrarily complex formulas to insert, and any actual formula *instance* that provides concrete values for $P$ and $Q$ will then have the said property, e.g. be true in all interpretations. We may instantiate the placeholder $P$ with the actual formula $(0=s0)$ and $Q$ with $(s0=0)$, and the theorem tells us that amongst others this formula is true in all interpretations, and therefore also in the standard model of arithmetic.

Satisfaction just means which formulas are true in which interpretations. Axioms are, by definition, true in all interpretations, so all interpretations satisfy all axioms (or more precisely, all concrete instances of the formula schemes which the axioms are).

Comment: I think I got it. I would make an edit just to make sure we are on the same page.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Except it's not clear what you mean by "a world that follows satisfaction". The satisfaction relation is defined for any interpretation. $\vDash \phi$ just means $\phi$ is true in (= is satisfied by) any interpretation whatsover.

Comment: Thanks. For "world that follows satisfaction" I guess I mean interpretation. For example "Natural numbers" or "Real numbers" or "Euclidean Geometry" or "Set Theory". From a personal philosophical position, the thing we try to formalize writing down specific mechanical and boring axioms to figure out what they mean or at least to fix their meaning (with no luck).

Comment: Coming back to earth, I guess from a mathematical perspective the only structures (a better name that world) we can talk about are constructions based on ZFC or similar set theories, isn't it?